# MAMP PRO Virtual Host directory on Mac Leopard OSX?

Tags: mamp

After accidentally deleting the 'mysql' database in my MAMP Pro installation this morning I decided to do a re-install. This seems to have resolved my original issue but I would like to restore all my virtual hosts from a Time Machine backup but I'm unsure where MAMP PRO stores these.

From memory I don't think they were stored with any hosts I had configured manually in 'etc/hosts'. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 17):

In MAMP Pro everything is in /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP Pro/

[Different than MAMP]

Comment: Correct answer for this question.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look in:

/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/

there should be some virtualhost configs in there

Comment: *"there should be"* is not really a razor sharp answer... See most upvoted answer.